# WiFi adapter not working at full speed

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless

I have a notebook HP with wifi adapter - Intel Corporation Centrino Ultimate-N 6300
And if I understood correctly this adapter has max-speed - 400Mbps, but I getting just 100-150Mbps. I tested it near the router. Router - new TP-LINK Archer A8. Is it possible to fix this somehow? Could you help me with it, please?
PS: If needed I can add some info from terminal

Answer (score 1):

I would start with running these commands in terminal

```
sudo sed -i 's/wifi.powersave = 3/wifi.powersave = 2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf
systemctl restart network-manager.service
sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi && sleep 5 && sudo modprobe iwlwifi 11n_disable=8
```

See if the speed improves